# Unable to replace/use relatvie image url with JavaScript. Absolute path works, relative does not

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added what I think are the important parts to the fiddle.  Basically, all my files are currently in one dir.  The CSS puts a background image on the div #slides using a relative path.  Then, using javascript and an array, I want to change the background image.  However, the js only works if I put in an absolute path to the image

The fiddle won't display the images, but the structure is there.  Normally, I have a function that increments i and displays the corresponding picture, but i didn't think that was necessary for troubleshooting.

The reason I'm trying to use relative paths is because i may need to be able to copy and paste the whole folder or use it from a usb drive on a pc that doesn't have internet access.

In dev console, when I set i = 1 and run the function, the background is blank.  When i have absolute paths set and do the same thing, it displays the correct picture according to the i value.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: when i combine all my code into the html doc, everything works with relative paths.  So, there must be something simple i'm missing when writing out the paths using different html/css/js files.

http://jsfiddle.net/xvs8ogjg/4/

HTML

```
<div id="slides"></div>
```

CSS

```
/* I'm using % based sizes on the actual version, but everything else is the same. */

#slides {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;

    /* this css loads the first image properly when the page loads */
    background-image: url("test1.svg");

    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

JS

```
//Array with images.  Images, css, and js are all in the same folder called slideshow for now.

var slides = document.getElementById('slides');

//Does not work
var images = new Array (
    "test1.svg",
    "test2.svg"
);

//Does not work, i thought i could trick it or something, idk
var images = new Array (
    "../slideshow/test1.svg",
    "../slideshow/test2.svg"
);

//Works
var images = new Array (
    "http://example.com/directory/slideshow/test1.svg",
    "http://example.com/directory/slideshow/test2.svg"
);

//Also works, locally
var images = new Array (
    "file:///C:/Users/myname/directory/slideshow/test1.svg",
    "file:///C:/Users/myname/directory/slideshow/test2.svg"
);

var i = 0;

var change = function() {
slides.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + images[i] + '")';
};
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting editing the styles with the different relative paths to see if you can do it manually? At least then you could rule out a path/CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on where you are when you request the file from. There's also no way to see what you're describing from the plunkr because that will be relative to the plunker url.

```
//Does not work, i thought i could trick it or something, idk
var images = new Array (
    "/directory/slideshow/test1.svg",
    "/directory/slideshow/test2.svg"
);
```

Should work from any location on the domain. I generally avoid using `../` in urls.

Comment: Yeah, i knew it wouldn't show up in the fiddle, but i thought that would be an easier way to see all my code for people that were willing to help.

the problem with using /directory/ first is that the directory may change - could be desktop or C:/ or anything else depending on where i put it.

however, i did figure out that if i put the css and js in the html file, it all works as desired, which is nice, but kinda weird.  something about paths I'm clearly not understanding.

Comment: If the paths are going to be dynamic then your array of images should not be static. However you're fetching the array of images should also return the path to the image from the root of the domain.